# Downloading bulk .tgz virrs data using request python in a cicle

Tags: python, pandas, database, web, path

Hi I hope you can help me I'm trying a cycle where data is downloaded from https://eogauth.mines.edu/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&scope=email%20openid&client_id=eogdata_oidc&state=Ve5PHA-1qZho8xGl_m4Yp6W0kmI&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Feogdata.mines.edu%2Feog%2Foauth2callback&nonce=Gif2liognRQN5TXGNh-3AAmHKt6hU1pcQ6C_yMHtAAw

The files are in .tgz format which contain information from viirs and the NPP satellite . What is happening is that when the download is done the file only contains the URL and not the target file which would be a .tgz or a .tar. Thank you very much. The first parts of the code are for constructing the URLS

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import regex as re
import tarfile
import urllib
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import glob
import gzip
from io import BytesIO
import rasterio
import rasterio.plot
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


viirs_path = "https://eogdata.mines.edu/nighttime_light/monthly/v10/"
layer_colombia = "/Users/jagudelo/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-UniversidaddelosAndes/Observatorio CEDE_NEW/Herramientas/Mapa/Colombia_viirs_layer.rds"


# 2 tipos de datos vcm y vcmsl


def gen_fullpath(mes_inicio, mes_final, tipo):
    datos = tipo + "cfg/"
    anos = [2020, 2021]
    meses = [i for i in range(mes_inicio, mes_final + 1)]
    format_mes = []
    for x in meses:
        x = str(x)
        if len(x) < 2:
            x = "0" + str(x) + "/"
            format_mes.append(x)
        else:
            x = str(x) + "/"
            format_mes.append(x)
    format_ano = []
    for x in anos:
        x = str(x)
        x = x + "/"
        format_ano.append(x)

    ano_mes = []
    for x in anos:
        for y in format_mes:
            path = str(x) + y
            ano_mes.append(path)

    Lista_full_path = []
    for x in format_ano:
        for y in ano_mes:
            fullpath = viirs_path + x + y + datos
            Lista_full_path.append(fullpath)

    return Lista_full_path


def path_dawnload():
    url = gen_fullpath(mes_inicio=1, mes_final=12, tipo="vcmsl")
    Lista_path = []
    for x in url:
        page = requests.get(x)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
        if page.status_code == 200:
            links = soup.find_all(href=True)
            for link in links:
                link = link['href']
                if ".tgz" in link and "75N180W" in link:
                    path = x + link
                    Lista_path.append(path)
        else:
            print("No se encontro la pagina web")
    return Lista_path

Lista_path=path_dawnload()

import sys
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from pathlib import Path
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

def  dawnload():
    user = ******
    password = ******
    for liks in tqdm(Lista_path):
        x = liks.split("/")
        pathtgz = x[-1]
        pathtgz = pathtgz.split(".")
        pathtgz =pathtgz[0]
        response = requests.get(liks, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, password),stream=True,allow_redirects=True)
        response.raise_for_status()
        if response.status_code == 200:
            text_file = open(pathtgz, "wb")
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                text_file.write(chunk)
            text_file.close()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The mistake is only in the last function that is named download()